# How can I play sound effects in React Native tvOS version

Tags: react-native, tvos

I'm making a new game for the apple TV using React Native (version `0.47.2`, support for apple tv is fully exists on this version, see here [RN for TVOS Docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/building-for-apple-tv.html))

everything is working great, but unfortunately I'm not able to play sounds at all.
I've tried `react-native-sounds` and `react-native-sound-player` and in both I'm getting an error caused by a missing library called `RNSound`.

The only thing I've learned so far regarding this issue is that if a library is missing I go to my Xcode project and switch to the `-tvOS` build and then link the tvOS version of the library I need and it usually works.
In this case, I'm not able to find a tvOS version of this library. (I'm not sure this is the solution but this way worked before)

The error looks something like this:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that there was no support in non of this libraries for tvOS.

Big shoutout for [dlowder-salesforce](https://github.com/dlowder-salesforce) for adding tvOS support for the `react-native-sounds` library

(if hes PR is not yet merged you can add the following to your package.json:

`"react-native-sound": "https://github.com/dlowder-salesforce/react-native-sound#master"`
)